# ASP.NET MVC smtp error sending mail problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp

I have already edited the webconfig file but I've got `SmtpException "error sending mail"`. My domain port is 25. I've double checked. Here is my code. What's problem? Thank you.

```
public void SendEmail(string toAddress, string fromAddress,string subject, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var mail = new MailMessage())
            {


                mail.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress));
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = message;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                try
                {
                    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        smtpClient.Host = "webmail.domain.com";
                        smtpClient.Port = 25;
                        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("blabla@domain.com", "pass");
                        smtpClient.Send(mail);
                    }

                }
                    mail.Dispose();   
            }
        }
```

Comment: `smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;` is required if your email service is encrypted

Comment: İ ve already tried it. nothing change

Comment: Which email provider you're using? Different providers have different credentials, host and port settings, you need to mention provider name which currently used by `SmtpClient`.